# microphone volume control from javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, html, microphone

I'd like to be able to control the system microphone volume from the browser.

I know that the microphone can be recorded from using Flash or Silverlight, but these don't allow control of the microphone volume.  (Flash has [Microphone.gain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#gain), but as its just a software multiplier, it doesn't help when the system mic volume is muted or too loud.)  I suppose the mic could be modified via a Trusted Java Applet via JNI, but getting Java installed on a user's computer is hard for non-savvy users.  (Not to mention the problems with getting an Applet to consistently load.)

I've heard that HTML5 will have some sort of microphone access, but whether it will allow volume control is unclear to me.  At any rate, I don't think any browsers support it yet.

Are there any plugins that would allow volume control?  The old Google Gears project has some [AudioApi](http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/AudioAPI) docs, though these don't seem to have made it into the actual plugin.  There's also the [Google Talk plugin](http://www.google.com/talk/)- it seems to do some kind of gain control, but its unclear if there's an api to the plugin.

Perhaps there's a draft HTML5 implementation plugin for microphone access (like [indexeddb](http://code.google.com/p/indexeddb/), for example)?

Comment: I really, really hope that this is not possible. I'll keep an eye on this question so I can find out what stuff not to install :-)

Comment: would be a great idea to control the webcam too, no? </sarcasm>

Comment: Apparently you sarcastic guys have never tried to get non-savvy users to set up their microphone properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verdict is that it would be a security concern. There is no way the system microphone volume can be changed by a browser application unless a plugin is used, just like there is no way to change the system speaker volume. However, you can amplify or reduce the input stream in Flash or Java.

Comment: If the browser prompted you for permission (like Flash does) it wouldn't be a security concern.  The issue here is that getting non-savvy users to fix their microphone is extremely painful (or impossible).  There needs to be some kind of automated solution.  Anyway, my question is whether there are any plugins that do this.

Comment: Also, as I said in my question you *cannot* change the volume in Flash.  It is just a software multiplier.  Tho it is true that it could be done with a Trusted Java Applet...

Comment: Oh, whether there are any plugins? Not to my knowledge, but you can easily enough make one. And yes, I was talking about the software multiplier in Flash. I didn't know that Java had access to the system volume, though. If they could just trust/accept the Java program's certificate, can't you use that?

Comment: Using Trusted Java could work. But getting Java installed on a user's computer and then getting the applet to load properly is no small feat.

Comment: Most people have Java installed. If you use Java 1.1 or earlier, you should be all set.

Comment: @Anonymous, sure, but who wants to wait the 6 days it takes to load Java?  Plus, who's Java installations actually work properly?  If it weren't for these issues, we'd be using Java for everything.  Sadly, these minor hurdles have really messed up thing on web pages for us...

Comment: The major hurdle is the use of Jar files. Class files load way faster. There is nothing to decompress, and it never makes it to the hard drive.

Comment: Ugh, getting Java sound working inside an applet; thinking about that makes me strangely depressed ...

Comment: Don't be so negative, Pointy. This guy's talking about changing system settings for the use of another application. I'm sure Brad wouldn't want to implement the whole thing in Java.

Comment: Since JavaSound is broken on Macs, making this work cross-platform will probably require JNI.  And I agree with the comments about the problems with getting jars loaded / problems with Java versions-- its a huge pain.  I was hoping there would be some other method than using Java Applets.

Comment: Then I suppose a plugin it is. I didn't know JavaSound wasn't working on Macs, that sucks. The JNI could work just as well though, so long as you have a fix for each machine. It would be the same if you made your own plugin.